# How to disable automatic transition of MaterializeCss carousel?

Tags: html, carousel, transition, materialize

I have carousel which displays video slides. The problem with that while playing the current video the carousel automatically transfers the view to the next corousel-item video. How do I solve this issue? Is it a bad way to display a video gallery using carousel?

```
<h4 class="stylish_headline center ">-Video Gallery-</h4>

<?php $rows= $data["img"];?>
<div class="row" id="posts">

    <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
        <div class="carousel " data-indicators="true" style="margin-top:  -80px;" >

            <?php
            foreach ($rows as $row){?>
            <a class="carousel-item "  href="#one!" style=" width: 300px !important;">
                <video class="responsive-video" controls>
                  <source src="video/<?= $row['VIDEO_LINK'] ?>" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </a>
            <?php }?>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" >
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({ 

    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you post for code for the carousel please?

Comment: I have added the source @JoshAdams

Comment: a few ideas you could stop the auto sliding all together with setting interval to false or use .carousel('pause') on click

Comment: I will try the pause part but setting interval to false doesn't work!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53038579/8437974 Check this @Dhrubanka